# Unity Touch Pressure with iOS iPad

Tags: unity, mobile, ipad

I've implemented this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-pressure.html. It is always returning 1, which makes me think that touch pressure is not a feature of the device.

The only issue is that the device is an iPad 7th generation, which works with my Apple pencil. My other iPad is an 8th generation. Both devices should provide touch pressure metrics, but they always come back as 1. Am I misunderstanding something about what touch pressure is meant to be here, or is compatibility with a pencil/haptic touch not the same as touch pressure?

If this doesn't work for whatever reason, how can I get touch pressure on an iPad through Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressure sensitivity for the Apple Pencil is built into the Pencil, not the display. This is fairly common for pressure-sensitive drawing tools.

[image: Cropped version of official Pencil webpage showing that sensitivity is built into the stylus]

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_Touch), iPhone generations 6 - X had some models with pressure-sensitive displays, but this feature has been discontinued, and was never used in iPads.

Also, as it says in the documentation that you linked to, you can use `Input.touchPressureSupported` to see if the device has a pressure-sensitive touchscreen.